# Anything wrong with this trap message?

Tags: snmp, snmp-trap

I am using this Linux command to send snmp v2c traps.

```
snmptrap -m ./ibmConvergedPowerSystems.mib -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 0 IBM-CPS-MIB::problemTrap cpsSystemSendTrap s "This is a test"
```

I am receiving this.

[image]

The way I am reading it is that it's got 3 OIDs.

1. sysUpTime oid (".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0") - which is 0.
2. snmpTrapOID (".1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0") - which contains OID for this -> http://www.oidview.com/mibs/2/IBM-CPS-MIB.html
3. Enterprise specific trap with data (data for IBM-CPS-MIB).

Did I get it right?

Only thing I care about is #3. Is there a way to modify the command to get rid of the other two OIDs. Or v2c trap will always have the first two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty normal Enterprise specific SNMP notification. The type of this notification (PDU format) is TRAPv2. This trap contains 3 varbinds. The first two are required by [RFC1448](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1448#page-26). So you cannot get rid of them.

- The first varbind `snmpTrapOID.0` is the actual Object Identifier (OID) that identifies the type of Trap.
- The second varbind `sysUptime.0` is from RFC1213 (MIB-2). Basically it is the time since device was last rebooted.

I would add `.0` to `cpsSystemSendTrap` as it is a scalar object.

Comment: I posed a follow up question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319026/is-snmptrapenterprise-required-in-snmp-v2c

The consumer of the trap above is expecting snmpTrapEnterprise as the last varbind. Is it needed for enterprise specific trap?